Add dependencies but unable to connect H2-database on my Spring Boot Gradle-Groovy project
I am trying to run the H2 database on my Spring Boot Gradle Groovy project and have added all the dependencies, but the database is not running. When I enter the database URL, it shows a Whitelabel Error Page.
here is my build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.6'
}

group = 'com.packt'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(22)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:3.1.0'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

application.properties
spring.application.name=cardatabase
server.port=8081
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:accounttestdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console


Here is the result showing

Please [edit] your question to convert images into text, and use a [code
block] for any code you have. Readers can then search the text or run
the code to reproduce your issue.

You need to use spring-starter-jpa to enable auto configuration of h2 by Spring. Here is how your pom.xml dependencies should look like:
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
  runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
  testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}


The spring-starter-jpa dependency must be added to the dependencies. The com.h2database:h2 dependency must be added to both testImplementation and runtimeOnly. If com.h2database:h2 is only added to runtimeOnly, the database is only showing and not connecting. Therefore, it must be added to testImplementation to ensure the connection.
build.gradle dependencies look like:

    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
        developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
        runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
        testImplementation 'com.h2database:h2'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
        testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
    }
    ```


